# Can't automation test for registration form with reCaptcha with selenium (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I have a problem with reCaptcha on my registration form. I have automated everything but I cannot bypass reCaptcha in order to complete registration. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction in order to find a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you provide an example or more detail?  The purpose of reCaptcha is to prevent automation.  You're not supposed to be able to bypass it.  Are you trying to write a test that must be automated?  What have you tried to bypass reCaptcha?

Comment: I need to automate a registration form. The problem is when I fill all fields with valid data I need to resolve reCaptcha manually. Can I do something to disable reCaptcha or something else?

Answer (score 1):

reCaptcha is designed to prevent automation bypassing.

The best practice is to disable it for test builds (just ask dev team to implement some test profile and disable reCaptcha).

Another option (which I not recommend) is to use solve-captcha-services, which provide some API for integrate it to automation script.
https://prowebscraper.com/blog/top-10-captcha-solving-services-compared/